# How to update reference of reference-type passed by value

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment, pass-by-value, ref

I'm working with a framework that passes objects between classes by value and I need to update the reference to one of those objects. I can change property values of the original object just fine but I can't seem to figure out how to change the reference to an entirely new object. In one of the latter classes I'm retrieving a rather complex object from an API, hence my desire to just update a reference rather than attempt a deep copy.

I've tried calling `SwapPerson{One,Two,Three,Four}` in my code sample with no hint of success. The output is always:

```
Main.person: Groucho Marx is 128 years old!
Main.person: Groucho Marx is 129 years old!
Main.person: Groucho Marx is 129 years old!
```

I'm hoping there's a simple solution that I'm overlooking due to the late hour, so any input is greatly appreciated.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName} is {Age} years old!";
        }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        private Person person;

        public Foo(Person person)
        {
            this.person = person;
        }

        public void SetAge(int age)
        {
            person.Age = age;
        }

        public void SwapPersonOne(Person newPerson)
        {
            person = newPerson;
        }

        public void SwapPersonTwo(ref Person newPerson)
        {
            person = newPerson;
        }

        public void SwapPersonThree(Person newPerson)
        {
            LocalSwap(ref person);

            void LocalSwap(ref Person oldPerson)
            {
                oldPerson = newPerson;
            }
        }

        public void SwapPersonFour(Person newPerson)
        {
            LocalSwap(ref person, ref newPerson);

            void LocalSwap(ref Person oldPerson, ref Person _newPerson)
            {
                oldPerson = _newPerson;
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person { FirstName = "Groucho", LastName = "Marx", Age = 128 };

        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Main)}.{nameof(person)}: {person}");

        var foo = new Foo(person);

        foo.SetAge(129);

        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Main)}.{nameof(person)}: {person}");

        var charlie = new Person { FirstName = "Charlie", LastName = "Chaplin", Age = 130 };

        //foo.SwapPersonOne(charlie);
        //foo.SwapPersonTwo(ref charlie);
        //foo.SwapPersonThree(charlie);
        foo.SwapPersonFour(charlie);

        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Main)}.{nameof(person)}: {person}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You need to clone the object, otherwise you are still pointing to the same memory address. Implement IClonable.

Comment: @Fleshy, I'm looking to update the reference of the original object, I don't think cloning is the solution.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of what `ref` means in C#; it is confusing. It has nothing whatsoever to do with *reference to an object*.  `ref` is better understood in C# as "alias of a variable".  When you have a function `Foo(ref T y)` and call it `Foo(ref x)` that means that `x` and `y` are *both names of the same variable*; they are *aliases* for each other. Now that you know that `ref` means "alias a variable" is the meaning of your program more clear?

Comment: In particular, your `SwapPersonTwo` is indistinguishable in its behaviour from `SwapPersonOne`, since you never write to the ref'd variable. Passing the value of a variable, and making an alias of a variable, are logically the same thing if the variable is never *written*. Make sure you understand that.

Comment: @EricLippert, thank you for the clarification -- I think the confusion stems from my usage of pointers back in my c++ days (which are a fading memory at this point). To your knowledge, is there any way to actually get and then change a reference to an object in C#?

Comment: When you say "get and change a reference to an object", references are *values*; they're like integers. So you're talking about changing *a stored value*. What is "a thing that can store a value?" That's a *variable*.  A variable is just storage for a value. The way you pass around a variable programmatically is via `ref`, which makes an *alias* to a variable; it makes two variables refer to *the same storage*.

Comment: So the question then is *what is the variable whose value you wish to change?* That is the thing that should be passed as `ref`, or, if you are only changing it and not reading it, pass it as `out`. Then make sure you actually change it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `ref` keyword within the inner local function, but not in the outer function. Also, if the intention is actually to *swap* the references, the method doesn't do that as-is.

```
    public void SwapPersonFour(Person newPerson)
    {
        LocalSwap(ref person, ref newPerson);

        void LocalSwap(ref Person oldPerson, ref Person _newPerson)
        {
            oldPerson = _newPerson;
        }
    }
```

`oldPerson` and `_newPerson` are passed to the local function by reference, but `newPerson` is passed to `SwapPersonFour` by value.

Also, only `oldPerson` is updated, so now both `oldPerson` and `_newPerson` refer to the same `Person`.

If you want to update the reference passed to `SwapPersonFour` you must also pass that argument by reference using the `ref` keyword.

```
public void SwapPersonFour(ref Person newPerson)
```

---

The comment mentioned that it didn't work, so I put together a hasty unit test to see if I was missing something. (I miss stuff all the time, which is why I write unit tests.)

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Person _person;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSwappingPerson()
    {
        _person = new Person { FirstName = "Scott" };
        var newPerson = new Person() { FirstName = "Bob" };
        SwapPersonFour(ref newPerson);
        Assert.AreEqual("Bob", _person.FirstName);
    }

    public void SwapPersonFour(ref Person newPerson)
    {
        LocalSwap(ref _person, ref newPerson);

        void LocalSwap(ref Person oldPerson, ref Person localNewPerson)
        {
            oldPerson = localNewPerson;
        }
    }
}
```

`SwapPersonFour` replaces the `_person` field with a reference to `newPerson`. It's not actually swapping anything because while it's updating `_person` it's not updating `newPerson`. When it's done they are both references to the same `Person`. (Did you mean to swap them? That could be the problem.)

For what it's worth, I would remove the local function because it doesn't actually do anything. It just takes the one thing that the method does and nests it in an extra function. You could replace it with this and get the same result - it's just easier to read. (In fact, the extra code might have made it easier to miss that nothing was getting swapped. I don't know about you, but it doesn't take much to confuse me.)

```
public void SwapPersonFour(ref Person newPerson)
{
    _person = newPerson;
}
```

If you actually want to swap them then you could do this:

```
public void SwapPersonFour(ref Person newPerson)
{
    var temp = _person;
    _person = newPerson;
    newPerson = temp;
}
```

Comment: Using `ref` in the outer function still has the same result:

            public void SwapPersonFive(ref Person newPerson)
            {
                LocalSwap(ref person, ref newPerson);

                void LocalSwap(ref Person oldPerson, ref Person _newPerson)
                {
                    oldPerson = _newPerson;
                }
            }

Comment: Another minor detail: It's a common convention to prefix fields with `_name`, but not variables or method arguments. That way when someone sees `_name` they know that it's a field, not a local variable. It's small, but over time we depend on little things like that to help us read code. I recommend trying a free Resharper demo. Even if you don't buy it, for a few weeks it will point those things out and suggest corrections, and after a few times the convention becomes habit.

Comment: Swap was a poor choice for the method name -- I'm actually looking to replace the referenced object and discard the previous value. I believe your sample works as intended because `_person` is a field of the `UnitTest1` class and it's being referenced by methods within that class. I probably did a poor job describing the scenario and my sample code isn't that great either. I have an object being passed from class A to class B by value (I have no control over this). I then, inside class B, need to replace the object that was passed in and have that change be reflected in class A.